# Why is my date column showing up as empty?

Tags: python, pandas

I have calculations of a tick data file I get daily that I'm preparing to append to a table daily. The final DataFrame should show the ticker, average spread, max spread, and date. Everything else works fine except for the date column which shows up empty.

The tick data itself has a column named 'timestamp' showing the time in the format e.g. 2016-06-03T14:27:16.548084-4:00. **I only need the date (2016-06-03), which should be the same on each row for each file I run this script on because each file is for one day**. Only the times differ.

The final result should look like:

```
a    | 0.22 | 1.84 | 2016-06-03
aa   | 0.01 | 0.10 | 2016-06-03
aaap | 2.07 | 2.17 | 2016-06-03
aal  | 0.15 | 0.5  | 2016-06-03
```

I've tried using dtype str as well and `df2['date'] = df['timestamp'].head(1) * len(df2.index)` with the same result, an empty date column. Where am I going wrong?

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
from datetime import datetime


df = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\tickdata.csv',
                 dtype={'ticker': str, 'timestamp': datetime, 'bidPrice': np.float32, 'askPrice': np.float32, 'afterHours': str},
                 usecols=['ticker', 'timestamp', 'bidPrice', 'askPrice', 'afterHours']
                 )

#afterhours and single sided quotes need to be filtered out
#create the spread column to analyze
df = df[df.afterHours == "False"]
df = df[df.bidPrice != 0]
df = df[df.askPrice != 0]
df['spread'] = (df.askPrice - df.bidPrice)

#compute the average and max to a seperate DataFrame
#grab the date from the first row
df2 = pd.DataFrame()
df2['avg_spread'] = df.groupby(['ticker'])['spread'].mean()
df2['maximum'] = df.groupby(['ticker'])['spread'].max()
df2['date'] = df['timestamp'].head(1)
```

UPDATE:

```
import pandas as pd
import numpy as np
import psycopg2 as pg
import datetime as dt


df = pd.read_csv('C:\\Users\\tickdata.csv',
                 dtype={'ticker': str, 'timestamp': str, 'bidPrice': np.float32, 'askPrice': np.float32, 'afterHours': str},
                 usecols=['ticker', 'timestamp', 'bidPrice', 'askPrice', 'afterHours'],
                 )
#afterhours and single sided quotes need to be filtered out
#create the spread column to analyze
df = df[df.afterHours == "False"]
df = df[df.bidPrice != 0]
df = df[df.askPrice != 0]
df['spread'] = (df.askPrice - df.bidPrice)

#convert timestamp to date
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
df['date'] = df.timestamp.dt.date

#compute the average and max to a seperate DataFrame
#grab the date from the first row
df2 = pd.DataFrame()
df2['avg_spread'] = df.groupby(['ticker'])['spread'].mean()
df2['maximum'] = df.groupby(['ticker'])['spread'].max()
df2['date'] = df.groupby(['ticker'])['date']
```

Now trying to figure out how to get the date displayed in df2. Tried     `df2['date'] = df.groupby(['ticker'])['date']`
and

```
df2['date'] = df['date']
```

UPDATE 2[SOLVED]
Needed to use
`df2['date'] = df.groupby(['ticker'])['date'].first()`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use to_datetime to convert to datetime and dt.date to get the date string.

```
df['timestamp'] = pd.to_datetime(df['timestamp'])
df['date'] = df.timestamp.dt.date
```

Comment: Thanks! I got the date separated now. Follow-up question: for the final DataFrame (df2), how do I get the 'date' column? It's displayed fine in the original DataFrame (df) but I can't seem to get it displayed in df2 and I think it has something to do with the columns using groupby; however, using the same concept for date: df2['date'] = df.groupby(['ticker'])['date'] doesn't work, nor does df2['date'] = df['date']. Updated code in OP!

Comment: You need to use an agg function like first `df.groupby(['ticker'])['date'].first()` depending on what you aim to aggregate

Comment: What I think you want though is to group by ticker and date: `df.groupby(['ticker', 'date']).agg({'avg_spread': ['min', 'max']})`

Comment: I think your suggestion of using `df2['date'] = df.groupby(['ticker'])['date'].first()` is right and am currently waiting for the script to finish to confirm. You are close but it's a bit simpler: I run this script each day to append to a table so the dates will be entirely the same in df2 so if the date is 2016-06-03, it will be 2016-06-03 for the entire column. I'm just confused on the syntax to get it to display that from df to df2.